# Canvas.drawRect() with Rect.fromLTRB() not working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

In my flutter app, I tried to use `CustomPainter`, to draw custom shapes.

Here, I want to draw 4 small squares, in different colors, in a bigger square (here in yellow).

I expected to see the 4 squares, but for some reason, the 4 squares are on the top left of the `CustomPainter`.

Here is my sample app:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.amber,
          width: 180,
          height: 180,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: TestCustomPainter(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {

  Paint _paintWhite = Paint()
    ..color = Colors.white
    ..isAntiAlias = true;
  Paint _paintBlue = Paint()
    ..color = Colors.blue
    ..isAntiAlias = true;
  Paint _paintRed = Paint()
    ..color = Colors.red
    ..isAntiAlias = true;
  Paint _paintGreen = Paint()
    ..color = Colors.green
    ..isAntiAlias = true;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawRect(Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, 90, 90), _paintWhite);
    canvas.drawRect(Rect.fromLTRB(90, 0, 0, 90), _paintBlue);
    canvas.drawRect(Rect.fromLTRB(0, 90, 90, 0), _paintRed);
    canvas.drawRect(Rect.fromLTRB(90, 90, 0, 0), _paintGreen);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;

}
```

And here is what I get:
[image: Here is what I get]

What did I do wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: you are passing wrong params to `Rect.fromLTRB` - for example: `Rect.fromLTRB(90, 0, 0, 90)` - left is `90` and right is `0`

Comment: left should be `90` and right `180`, dont you think?

Comment: @pskink Why are they wrong params, since I want that one to be on the top right corner of the big yellow square? What params should I use, then?

Comment: `Rect.fromLTRB(90, 0, 180, 90)` but it is easier to use `Rect.fromLTWH` - so you always use `Rect.fromLTWH(x, y, 90, 90)`

Comment: @pskink ok so it works with left `90` and right `180`, but I don't understand why: isn't right supposed to be the distance between the right side of my small square and the right side of the bigger square?

Comment: what bigger square? `Canvas.drawRect` knows nothing about "bigger square" - it only draws a `Rect`

Comment: Well, I thought `CustomPainter ` was aware of the edges, since `size` is correct (180 x 180), but ok, thanks for the help!

Comment: @pskink You can post an answer so I'll upvote and accept it, if you want.

Comment: post a self answer then ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.amber,
          width: 180,
          height: 180,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: TestCustomPainter(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {

  Paint _paintWhite = Paint()
    ..color = Colors.white
    ..isAntiAlias = true;
  Paint _paintBlue = Paint()
    ..color = Colors.blue
    ..isAntiAlias = true;
  Paint _paintRed = Paint()
    ..color = Colors.red
    ..isAntiAlias = true;
  Paint _paintGreen = Paint()
    ..color = Colors.green
    ..isAntiAlias = true;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawRect(Rect.fromLTRB(90, 0, 180, 90), _paintWhite);
    canvas.drawRect(Rect.fromLTRB(90, 0, 0, 90), _paintBlue);
    canvas.drawRect(Rect.fromLTRB(0, 90, 90, 180), _paintRed);
    canvas.drawRect(Rect.fromLTRB(180, 180, 90,90), _paintGreen);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;

}
```

since

> Rect.fromLTRB(double left, double top, double right, double bottom)
> Construct a rectangle from its left, top, right, and bottom edges.

more info about this over here in docs https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Rect-class.html